# Why the simple multiplication would result in some garbled characters?

Tags: c++, calculator

I try to design a program that implements the multiplication between two big integers(Using C++). But after I complete it, I found that if I input the two integers by the command arguments, the results would be sometimes very weird and sometimes right. Please help me figure out the reason and tell me how to fix it. Thanks (The main function that implements the function of multiplication between two big integers is **mul()** ).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void mul(char *c1, char *c2, int len1, int len2);

void printArr(char *c1, char *c2, int len1, int len2);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argv[1] != NULL)
    {
        char cArr1[500], cArr2[500];
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)
        {
            cArr1[i] = argv[1][i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[2]); i++)
        {
            cArr2[i] = argv[2][i];
        }
        int len1 = strlen(cArr1);
        int len2 = strlen(cArr2);
        printArr(cArr1, cArr2, len1, len2);
        (len1 > len2) ? mul(cArr1, cArr2, len1, len2) : mul(cArr2, cArr1, len2, len1);
        exit(100);
    }
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Please input two integers" << endl;
        char cArr1[500], cArr2[500];
        cin >> cArr1;
        if (cArr1[0] == 'q' && cArr1[1] == 'u' && cArr1[2] == 'i' && cArr1[3] == 't')
        {
            exit(1000);
        }
        cin >> cArr2;
        int parity = 0;
        int len1 = strlen(cArr1);
        int len2 = strlen(cArr2);
        printArr(cArr1, cArr2, len1, len2);
        if (cArr1[0] == '-')
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < len1; i++)
            {
                cArr1[i - 1] = cArr1[i];
            }
            parity++;
            len1--;
        }
        if (cArr2[0] == '-')
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < len2; i++)
            {
                cArr2[i - 1] = cArr2[i];
            }
            parity++;
            len2--;
        }
        bool isDigit = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++)
        {
            if (!isdigit(cArr1[i]))
            {
                isDigit = false;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < len2; i++)
        {
            if (!isdigit(cArr2[i]))
            {
                isDigit = false;
            }
        }
        if (!isDigit)
        {
            cout << "\rInvalid input. Try again" << endl;
            continue;
        }
        if (parity % 2 != 0)
        {
            cout << "-";
        }
        (len1 > len2) ? mul(cArr1, cArr2, len1, len2) : mul(cArr2, cArr1, len2, len1);
    }
}

void mul(char *bigger, char *smaller, int bigLen, int smallLen)
{
    int *bigNum = new int[bigLen];
    int *smallNum = new int[smallLen];
    for (int i = 0; i < bigLen; i++)
    {
        bigNum[i] = bigger[bigLen - i - 1] - '0';
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < smallLen; i++)
    {
        smallNum[i] = smaller[smallLen - i - 1] - '0';
    }
    int res[30];
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        res[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < smallLen; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < bigLen; j++)
        {
            res[i + j] += bigNum[j] * smallNum[i];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < bigLen + smallLen; i++)
    {
        int digit = res[i] % 10;
        int carry = res[i] / 10;
        res[i] = digit;
        res[i + 1] += carry;
    }
    bool null = false;
    for (int i = bigLen + smallLen - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (res[i] != 0 && res[i + 1] == 0)
        {
            null = true;
        }
        if (null)
        {
            cout << res[i];
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void printArr(char *c1, char *c2, int len1, int len2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++)
    {
        cout << c1[i];
    }
    cout << " * ";
    for (int i = 0; i < len2; i++)
    {
        cout << c2[i];
    }
    cout << " = ";
}
```

Comment: please include example input and example output. `int res[30];` looks like it can easily overflow

Comment: why are you not using `std::string` and `std::vector` ? They have element access with bounds checking, which helps to eleminate the most frequent errors

Comment: One possible issue is that: when you copy argv[1] and argv[2] to cArr1 and cArr2, it doesn't include the terminal '\0', then the calculation of len1 and len2 won't always correct depends on the status of the memory content.

Comment: Clearly, you  are using C idioms but using C++. You should try to forget your C background, first step is using the standard library containers: std::array and/or std::vector

Comment: An example: Input "23" and "4" bu command line arguments, it sometimes print "23 * 4 = 92", and sometimes "23�o� * 4 = 4-4-14-56"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just initialize your char arrays to empty ones:

```
char cArr1[500] = {};
char cArr2[500] = {};
```

then, for the sake of clarity, assign the lengths from your arguments to two integers, casting them since the compiler might warn you about incompatibility between `size_t` and `int`.

```
int lenArg1 = 0;
int lenArg2 = 0;

lenArg1 = (int)strlen ( argv[1] );
lenArg2 = (int)strlen ( argv[2] );
```

Then, printing the lengths `len1` and `len2` for debugging purposes only:

```
int len1 = strlen ( cArr1 );
int len2 = strlen ( cArr2 );

cout << "len1 >> " + to_string(len1) <<endl;
cout << "len2 >> " + to_string(len2) <<endl;
```

In fact, as @Kevin SUN mentioned, it was possible that your argument reading steps were missing the null characters, however, after running some tests it seems to work fine just by initializing the char arrays.

Also, as mentioned in the comments you need to increase the size reserved for `res` array, I did it to 500

Compiled with `g++ -Wall main.cpp -o calc.exe` and running: `calc 10 100`

Without initialization you get problems like:

[image: random garbage]
[image: more random garbage]

after initializing, the output works just fine:

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell me why the problem is fixed with array initialization?

Comment: If you notice, without initializing the char arrays the length from the first one is wrong (where the input is: calc 10 100). Initialization both reserves memory and removed garbage contained in those memory locations, I believe. Remember that the system must parse null characters to indicate the end of a string. In fact, the problem from your original code only occurs when the first number entered is of length higher than 1 character (try it). If my answer helped, please mark it as the solution ;)